# Trying to post a wordpress comment on my site redirects to 127.0.0.1

Tags: comments

My commenting system used to work fine, but now it redirects to 127.0.0.1 whenever I try to post one.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to the default theme. Does it still happen? Is there a special rule in your .htaccess?

Comment: If this is a hack, then it's one of the funniest :)

Comment: I doubt this is a hack, I have solid security plugins installed.  If it is a hack, we'll see if they can hack disqus :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using All in One Security plugin for Wordpress, then try to uncheck 'Block Spambot Comment' checkbox in Spam Prevention' section Comment SPAM tab
*Check this if you want to apply a firewall rule which will block comments originating from spambots*. I fixed that issue like this. Seems that this feature not really working properly :)

Comment: Bingo! (It's nice when an answer is exactly right and let's you solve the problem immediately.  Thanks!) It's a shame the function breaks comments altogether. Hopefully AIOWPS will fix it.

Comment: Thanks, man, you are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If deactivating all the plugins does not solve the problem it may be a problem with your .htaccess file, especially if you have installed/activated a plugin that deals with comments in any way.
You can generate a new basic .htaccess file by:

1. Access your hosting account cpanel and select the File Manager.
2. Delete the .htaccess file in the root directory of your WordPress installation.
3. Go back to the WordPress dashboard of your website and select Settings - Permalinks.
4. Click on Save and WordPress will generate a new .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I went ahead and just installed Disqus since I don't have time to troubleshoot this right now.  Got to take care of other things on the site, plus Disqus seems to provide some features that the default doesn't have anyway.

Comment: Definitely concerns me that this was happening.  I've also read about hosting providers disabling things in wordpress sometimes.  So it could have been that.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, issues similar to this one usually happen when you start developing your site locally and then import the database to the staging/live environment. Locally you worked with 127.0.0.1 and it was saved to "siteurl" and "home" options on the database, but on your wp-config.php you are setting [WP_HOME](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Blog_address_.28URL.29) and [WP_SITEURL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29) dynamically.

To fix this you would update "siteurl" and "home" options on your live database to match your domain, instead of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I had my site url and and wordpress url identical but did not know the http: was changed to https: and adding the s fixed everything!